# Copy all email address from continuous form into Outlook email To Line

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a continuous form in an Access Database that lists each employee assigned to a job and their email address.

I need to insert each email address into the To line in an Outlook email message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to perform the following operations in VBA in MS Access:

- Open a recordset of the query/table constituting the record source of your form - you can do this using the `recordsetclone` method of the form.
- Iterate over the recordset and construct a semi-colon delimited string using the value held by the email address field. Use the constructed string to populate the `To` field of the email.
- Alternatively, use the `Add` method of the `Recipients` property of the Mail Item to add each recipient as you iterate over the recordset.